# How to create a very small data source (1 or 2 tables) for an Android App on a server, not locally?

Tags: android, database

I am new in this field, so I know that Google's app engine is useful for me. But I do not quite get how to build the database and which data source should be used ?

I need 2 tables for my database to store my data, and I want to connect with that from the Android App, So how does this work ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a NoSQL database like [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

When using CouchDB you could even have one CouchDB instance running on your server and another one locally on your phone. Your app would work offline and synchronize wiht the server, when connection available.

Comment: So you are saying I do not use App Engine at all ?

Comment: Sorry If I was not clear from the beginning, but in my case, I will have to tables but they will be related to each other (one-to-many). This is not possible in CouchDB, right ?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is the solution and [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) is a nice and clean tutorial to refer for the SQLite database.

Comment: But isn't SQLite local on the device ?